# Change icon when the text is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to coding and I'm experimenting with hamburger-style menu.

What I've achieved: when the user clicks on the hamburger menu icon, it changes into the close icon.

I've added a text label in front of the hamburger menu icon, but the problem is that I don't know how to make this text change the icon when it's clicked.

If you can please advise on this matter.

Many thanks

Best regards,
Veaceslav

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Title</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Font Awesome -->

    <link href="Fontawesome/css/all.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="CSS/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

<!-- Header -->
    <header id="header" class="header d-flex align-items-center fixed-top">

    <div class="container-fluid container-xl d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">

        <a href="index.html" class="logo d-flex align-items-center"><h1>Logo</h1></a>
 
        <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">

            <ul class="nav-links">

            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_toggle"/>
            <label for="checkbox_toggle" class="hamburger"><span class="menu_text" onclick="changeIcon(fa-bars)">Menu</span> <i class="fa-solid fa-bars" onclick="changeIcon(this)"></i></label>
    
            <div class="menu">
    
                <li><a href="#">First</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Second</a></li>
            </div>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    </header>

<footer></footer>

</body>

<script src="Bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="JS/menu_icon_toggle.js"></script>

</html>
```

JS

```
 let changeIcon = function(icon) {
        icon.classList.toggle('fa-xmark')
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modifiy you changeIcon function as

```
let changeIcon = function () {
        document.getElementById("text_icon").classList.toggle("fa-xmark");
    };
```

And label tag as

```
<label for="checkbox_toggle" class="hamburger">
          <span
            id="menu_text_item"
            class="menu_text"
            onclick="changeIcon()"
          >
            Menu
          </span>
          <i class="fa-solid fa-bars" id="text_icon" onclick="changeIcon()">
          </i>
        </label>
```

onClicking menu text/icon don't pass anything, inside changeIcon function you can access icon node using document.getElementById and then toggle the css list